# CrossTab with 1 row in subreport causes extra whitespace

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, subreport

[DetailsA Subreport Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6lY3.png)

My report has a CrossTab in a subreport inside a group detail (`detailsA`). This is followed by a separate subreport with its own crosstab in a subsequent group detail section (detailsB).

When there is more than one row in the `detailsA` CrossTab, the combination of `detailsA` and `detailsB` look like a grid. But when there's only one row in `detailsA`, a space is created between the two. Depending on the information fed to my subreport, `detailsA` will be suppressed and only `detailsB` will appear.

There is no space in between `detailsA` and `detailsB`. I've tried adding a test text field directly underneath the crosstab in `detailsA` but the white space appears between the text field and the the cross tab.

How do I remove this extra space?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the design view? That might help me get a better handle on what solutions could/won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. From my understanding it cannot be deleted, and if we adjust the margin of the sections the blank space still appear.

To solve this, I added another report footer and wrote "this space is left blank". This works, but isn't really effective.